# Does Trump have bathmophobia-- a fear of slopes?

Tags: donald-trump

This really could be two questions.  First we have the image of Trump and May holding hands in this [article in the Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/01/28/revealed-real-reason-donald-trump-theresa-may-held-hands-not/).

Then they claim from an unsourced insider:

> But Government sources in Washington DC were suggesting that the hand-holding was not as a result of a deep and lasting friendship after all.
>
> The insider said that Mr Trump is known to have an aversion to slopes or stairs, and said this could have been the reason for the president's decision to grasp the Prime Minister’s hand.
>
> Such a fear is a recognised condition - called bathmophobia.

Any truth to this claim?

Comment: Warning: Diagnosing a non-patient is considered an breach of ethics for American psychiatrists (the [Goldwater Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwater_rule)). Breaking confidentiality about a diagnosis is a worse breach. Guessing at Trump's motivation for holding hands is off-topic here. I can't see how this can be legitimately answered, without Trump directly admitting it. Without that, the claim is rather defamatory against Trump.

Comment: Related: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/claims-involving-personal-information-about-notable-people

Comment: Agreed, I was thinking of focusing the question on whether he was previously gossiped to have this condition, but gossip isn't proof, and "is known to have" is a textbook example of "[weasel word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word)" which makes the statement unfalsifiable. A good attempt K Dog, but we can't address it IMO.

Comment: Did you mean bathrobephobia?